# Bash : Give builded array to function as a list of argument?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, array, arguments

I have this issue with borgbackup, but because the reaction is the same, I will use `rsync` in my example.

I want to build an array of arguments by adding a prefix to each, and then give that array to `rsync`. But `rsync` acts like it doesn't exist.

With this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#

declare -a exclude_String
for excludestr in $(cat ./list); do
    exclude_String+=(--exclude=$excludestr)
done
rsync "${exclude_String[@]}" . $Destination
```

and `./list`:

```
'/home/*'
'*.vim*'
```

A `ps` of the process running does shows the argument correctly:

```
/usr/bin/rsync --exclude='*.vim*' --exclude='/home/*' . DESTINATION
```

But `rsync` still acts like they aren't there. I found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152553/bash-string-concatenation-used-to-build-parameter-list) on the subject, so I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#

declare -a exclude_String
exclude_String+=(--exclude='/home/*')
exclude_String+=(--exclude='*.vim*')

rsync "${exclude_String[@]}" . $Destination
```

And this actually worked.

I don't understand much yet about shell expansion and stuff, I've tried to quote and double quote all over the place just to see if I could find something, but no luck.

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file actually contains `'/home/*'`, with the quotes, the quotes will be there in the value of `excludestr` in the loop, and then in the argument you give to `rsync`. They're not part of a shell command in that case, just part of the expanded value of the command substitution.

On the other hand, if you write `exclude_String+=(--exclude='/home/*')`, now the quotes *are* part of a shell command, and are removed during the processing of that command. (With the effect of making `*` an ordinary character.)

`rsync` doesn't actually expect or process quotes as part of the exclusion pattern, it will just treat them as any other character, and would exclude files with names containing quotes. So, if you have the exclusion patterns as data in some file, you shouldn't have the quotes there.

Also, instead of `for x in $(cat file)`, use `while IFS= read -r line; do ...; done < file`, or in this case, `mapfile -t exclude_String < file`. That command substitution with `cat` invokes word splitting, so you can't have exclusion patterns containing whitespace. It also invokes globbing of the patterns immediately, right there, on the list of words for the `for` loop. This isn't what you want.

---

In general, what you need is:

```
excludes=()
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    excludes+=(--exclude="$line")
done < ./list 
rsync "$flags" "${excludes[@]}" . "$destination"
```

With `./list` containing just the patterns to exclude:

```
/home/*
*.vim*
```

(The quotes around `"$line"` in `+=(--exclude="$line")` prevent the shell from globbing files called `--exclude=something` in the current directory.)

Though in the case of `rsync`, you might as well use `--exclude-from`:

```
rsync "$flags" --exclude-from=./list . "$destination"
```

If you're going to use something more complicated than a file to feed the loop, you can use process substitution:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    excludes+=(--exclude="$line")
done < <(some command that produces the exclude patterns)
```

See also: [Why is my variable local in one 'while read' loop, but not in another seemingly similar loop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9954/170373)

Comment: The issue with not putting ' in my source, is that now it is expended before being given to `rsync`, a `ps` of the process look like `/usr/bin/rsync --exclude=*.vim* --exclude=/home/user1 --exclude=/home/user2 . DESTINATION` and hidden file who aren't expended go through the filter.

Comment: @VlycopDoo, yeah... if you use `for x in $(cat file)`, the words in `file` will be used as globs right there, since the command substitution is unquoted. Another reason to use `while read` or `mapfile`, then. I added an example.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you could use `set -f; IFS=$'\n'; for line in $(cat file); do ...; done` and you'd get to read the file line-by-line, but I'm not sure that's very nice either.

Comment: Arggg... i used the cat method to simplify my question, but the way i do it in my real script is way more complicated. This mean that i have to rethink it all in order to never expend the parameter by accident, and without '. Thank's for putting the finger on the issue, but i fear i'm nowhere near done with this ^^

Comment: @VlycopDoo, it doesn't sound that bad, or at least not worse than shell programming usually. Just quote all the variables ;) (see [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694/170373) ) If you have a command that produces the exclude patterns, you'll want to check that "Why is my variable local..." question. But the easiest solution is to just use process substitution, which Kusalananda already commented on under their answer. See edit, too.

Answer (score 0):

[As ilkkachu explained](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/459709/116858), your issue is that the single quotes should not be part of the patterns and that if you write the patterns in a shell context, the shell will remove them.

However, it looks like you can bypass having to read you patterns explicitly from your file:

```
rsync --exclude-from=./list source/ target
```

With `--exclude-from=FILENAME`, `rsync` will read the exclusion patterns from the named `FILENAME`.  Note that when doing this, the patterns should not have those single quotes in them.

Comment: Thank's for your input. i was aware of this solution but it does not fit my use-case because i use a single file who both give what to backup, what to exclude, and what script to run before and after. You could not have know since i oversimplify my script for the question.

Comment: @VlycopDoo Ah, ok. If you're using `bash`, then you could do `rsync --exclude-from=<( command-that-parses-the-file ) ...`.